# How do I take a screenshot for a PlatformView Widget in Flutter Mobile Application?

Tags: flutter, screenshot, flutter-plugin

Here is the code I use to do a screenshot.

First, I placed the widget inside `RepaintBoundary`.

```
RepaintBoundary(
  key: widgetKey, 
  child: childWidget,
),
```

Then somewhere else in the code, we initiate a screenshot with the following code.

```
/// Note: Delay added to the actual code ensuring widget finish rendering.

final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = 
    widgetKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
```

The above code works for any widget except `PlatformView` widgets, which return an empty picture.

I've read the issues on Github [#25306](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25306) and [#83856](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83856).
They are closed, but the problem persists.

I've added a 2 seconds delay, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, as seen on the Github issue you sent: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83856 If the Flutter team itself hasn't fixed it yet, it's unlikely that someone else has, but not impossible.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think there is supposed to be a way to do native screenshots instead. But currently, the existing native screenshot plugin only captures the whole screen instead of a widget.

Comment: I would assume that happens because the native code is not aware of Flutter built widget.